# How to automatically edit a file (which requires hex editor) in ubuntu

Tags: scripts, programming

I have android boot image which needs to be patched evertime I flash a kernel.
The patching includes adding 4096 bytes to the boot image using a hex editor (I used ghex), which is very tedious process because you have to manually add 4096 numbers to the file by hand. So, I want to make a script to automate the process.

It is not like simply editing files, it requires hex editor.

To be specific I want to append 0x30, 0x83, 0x19, 0x89, 0x64 followed by 0x00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of thing you should be able to do with `dd`

***DISCLAIMER:*** remember that `dd` is known affectionately as the **d**isk **d**estroyer: please make sure you have adequate backups of the original files before trying this.

For example, let's first create a minimal test file:

```
$ printf 'hello' > testfile
$ xxd testfile
00000000: 6865 6c6c 6f                             hello
```

That's just 5 bytes of course - in reality it will be your image file.

Now we want to write a few more bytes, 0x30, 0x83, 0x19, 0x89, 0x64, padded with null bytes 0x00 up to a block size of (say) 128 bytes, and append it to the file. **This is just for illustration** - you will actually use `ibs=4096` in your case.

```
$ printf '\x30\x83\x19\x89\x64' | dd of=testfile ibs=128 conv=sync,notrunc oflag=append
0+1 records in
0+1 records out
128 bytes copied, 0.000500623 s, 256 kB/s
```

Let's check the result:

```
$ xxd testfile
00000000: 6865 6c6c 6f30 8319 8964 0000 0000 0000  hello0...d......
00000010: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000020: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000030: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000040: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000050: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000060: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000070: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000080: 0000 0000 00                             .....
```

which is the 5 bytes of the original `testfile`, followed by the new byte sequence padded to the 128-byte block size, for a total of 133 bytes (hexadecimal offset `00000085`).

Comment: I have one more question. If I want to add the bytes to a specific offset, Lets say 0xF35873. Can `dd` accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Both `head` and `tail` can, through their `--bytes` option, do surgery on your file.

```
# assume: boot.img is the to-be-modified file, my4096 is your 4096 bytes,
# and you want to replace bytes 4097-8192 of the file. newboot.img is the result.
( \
  head --bytes=4096 boot.img ;\
  cat my4096;\
  tail --bytes=+8193 boot.img \
) >newboot.img
```

or, you could use `ed`, or `sed`, or ...

Comment: I don't want to edit the existing bytes I want to append (at end) 0x30, 0x83, 0x19, 0x89, 0x64, followed by 0x00 till 4096 bytes are added.

Comment: Then, `cat my4096 >>boot.img` should do it.